# Klein-Gordon equation and Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I am facing hardships understanding these equations mainly due to the confusing terminologies used in books. Can anyone suggest an easy to read explanation and then one which has mathematically rigorous treatment of the same.

Comment: One text that has good physical motivation/understanding and goes through the math in very detailed explanations is Ryder's text on QFT. The most used textbook is the QFT book by Peskin & Schroeder but many people misunderstand how to use the book. Each page _should_ take multiple minutes or 10's of minutes. This is the one text where your notes and in-between-line derivations will be larger then the textbook itself. Peskin & Schroeder also has problems (unlike Ryder) where solutions are widely available online.

Comment: It may be worth asking a new more specific question about one example of terminology confusion, as you may learn something useful from an answer to it quite aside from any resource recommendations here. (If you have two or three examples in mind, it's best to give them a question each.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite is Itzykson&Zuber, Quantum Field Theory. The explicit and clear solution of these two equations for the hydrogen atom is very instructive and illuminating.